# Does Lemon Balm calm the nervous system?

Tags: psychology

Min Publications has an [alternative therapy article](http://www.mindpub.com/altern03.htm) that mentions:

> Around AD 1000, the Persian herbalist Avicenna recommended lemon balm "to make the heart merry." In Europe, this herb was sipped in cordials.

For a more modern source, the [University of Maryland Medical Center](http://www.umm.edu/altmed/articles/lemon-balm-000261.htm) explains:

> Lemon balm (Melissa officinalis), a member of the mint family, is considered a calming herb

Is it true?

Comment: Removed obsolete comments.

Comment: I started to write up a lengthy answer, explaining that there was a lot of research showing that Lemon Balm (a.k.a. Melissa officinalis) has some effect on mood, Alzheimer patients, colicky babies, etc. Then I looked more closely at the second link and found my references were all covered there. What are you looking for that the second link doesn't provide?

Comment: To be honest the OP did not add the second link, DVK did IIRC.